# Subprocess Python Module: Won't write .csv, but will do so if commands are run individually

Tags: python, bash, matlab, subprocess

I'm working on signal processing, and am of course working in python, but I have some matlab code which does some important preprocessing. Rather than rewriting to python, I thought I could make part of my pipeline run through matlab.

I've tried doing this through the `subprocess` python module because I know I can run matlab via terminal.

My question:

- My desired output from my matlab code is a .csv which I can use in python. But, why isn't my python code below creating the .csv? When I run the bash commands one by one in terminal, the file is created. I've also double checked my matlab syntax and scripts and they're fine.

```py
import subprocess

myBashCommands = [] #we'll populate this list with our desired bash commands to get the smooth PSD.
myBashCommands.append("cd /Applications/MATLAB_R2018b.app/bin") #go inside matlab package
myBashCommands.append("./matlab -nodesktop") #now we're in matlab via terminal
myBashCommands.append("potato_wav = audioread('potato-us.wav')") #create the .wav
myBashCommands.append("[f, t,  psd] = GetSpectrogram.m('potato_wav', 16000, 10)") #compute the spectrogram
myBashCommands.append("smooth_psd = smoothn(10*log(psd), .5)") #smooth it
myBashCommands.append("smooth_psd = SurfaceCubicInterpolator(smooth_psd)") #smooth the surface
myBashCommands.append("dlmwrite('smooth_psd.csv', smooth_psd, 'precision', ',', 'precision', '%.10f')") #overwrite or create a new .csv in the folder

subprocess.run(myBashCommands,stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell = True, check = True) #run all of these
```

Nothing is returned except a successful completed process message. If I use `subprocess.call`, I get a 0 returned, which also indicates a success.

Again, when I run all of those bash commands individually in a fresh terminal window, I get the .csv successfully.

Any thoughts on why the .csv won't be created when run dynamically with subprocess? I need this to take in arbitrary .wav files, so this seems like the least complicated way of doing this without creating some kind of bash script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subprocess` is a tricky tool. The first thing to be aware of is that each call to `subprocess.run()` is going to invoke *one* new process. Everything else will be treated as arguments to that new process (`argv` in C). Running the code you posted will translate to this:

```
cd /Applications/MATLAB_R2018b.app/bin [lots of other stuff...]
```

Since `cd` will do it's thing using the first argument and ignoring any additional arguments, it is completing successfully and returning.

Here is a test that demonstrates it more clearly:

```
>>> cmds=['cd .. ls who what where when why']
>>> sp.run(cmds, shell=True)
CompletedProcess(args=['cd .. ls who what where when why'], returncode=0)
```

If we add a `;pwd` to the end of `cmds[0]`, it will show one level up from whatever `os.getcwd()` shows. But subsequent calls to `os.getcwd()` will show the same location as it did originally.

The simple solution is to break all of your commands up into their own `subprocess.run()` calls. But that won't work quite right either. The reason is that things like `cd` don't get applied to your current session, so it won't work to change the working directory that way you are hoping.

To accomplish this using multiple `subprocess.run` calls would require 
 a combination of `subprocess` and some of the functions in the `os` module. Specifically, `os.chdir()`. But even then, you might also run into similar problems with the other commands and their arguments.

The quick and dirty way to do this is to put all the commands together, delimited by semicolons, but as one single string (much like you would do at the command prompt). Then, execute it using the `shell=True` argument to `run()` (which you are already doing). Basically, this:

```python
myBashCommands = ["cd /Applications/MATLAB_R2018b.app/bin;"]
myBashCommands[0] += "./matlab -nodesktop;"
[....]
subprocess.run(myBashCommands,stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell = True, check = True)
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, there is an extra layer of complexity here, in that the posted Python code actually contains embedded Matlab code. There are 2 easy ways to handle that:

1. put the Matlab code in a separate file, and use that file as input when invoking `matlab`. Something like this would probably work:

```
myBashCommands = ["cd /Applications/MATLAB_R2018b.app/bin;"]
myBashCommands[0] += "./matlab -nodesktop run('/path/to/script/file.m');"
subprocess.run(myBashCommands,stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell = True, check = True)
```

2. keep the embedded Matlab code inside the python script (this seems kind of kulgy to me), making sure the whole block is properly quoted and escaped, and give it to matlab as a command line argument:

```
myBashCommands = ["cd /Applications/MATLAB_R2018b.app/bin;"]
myBashCommands[0] += "./matlab -nodesktop 'potato_wav = audioread(\'potato-us.wav\'); [f, t,  psd] = GetSpectrogram.m(\'potato_wav\', 16000, 10); smooth_psd = smoothn(10*log(psd), .5); smooth_psd = SurfaceCubicInterpolator(smooth_psd); dlmwrite(\'smooth_psd.csv\', smooth_psd, \'precision\', \',\', \'precision\', \'%.10f\')"
subprocess.run(myBashCommands,stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell = True, check = True)
```

Comment: An extra issue here is that the matlab code will be executed in the shell, once matlab finishes. So you need to redirect the matlab input to matlab.

Comment: You're correct when you said this is quite tricky; I can't thank you enough for lending your expertise! I tried this and it worked after fixing some of the quotes for bash.  But thank you!